# Excess of OH- ions in electrolysis of sodium chloride solution

Tags: redox, electrolysis

In the electrolysis of dilute or concentrated sodium chloride solution, at the cathode as hydrogen ions discharge and cause an excess of hydroxide ions, why doesn't the negativity of the cathode repel the hydroxide ions as the electrode is the negative electrode?

Comment: The reaction taking place at the cathode is : $\ce{2 H2O + 2 e- -> 2 OH- + H2}$  The negative $\ce{OH-}$ ions are repelled by the cathode as soon as they are produced. They pass into solution where they neutralize the $\ce{Na+}$ ions which have been attracted by the negative cathode, and cannot be discharged.

Comment: The site expects that you include the compact summary of your related current knowledge, involving your conclusion of searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. It also serves as evidence of your mandatory effort. Effort not shown can be considered as effort not done, possibly leading to the question closure. [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).